# Unable to upload image using shell in django

Tags: python, django

I am newbie on dJango/python. I am trying python shell to save data using model. I have done as:

**Model**

```
class Author(models.Model):
salutation = models.CharField(max_length=10)
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
email = models.EmailField()
headshot = models.ImageField(upload_to='/tmp')

def __str__(self):
    return '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

Now I have tried the command in shell:

```
>>> from books.models import Author
>>> a = Author(salutation='Mr.',
... first_name='First Name',
... last_name='Last Name',
... email='myemail@myemail.com')
```

Then I have put an image in the project's tmp directory and run following the command:

```
a.headshot.save('/abc.jpg', Author(open('/tmp/pic.jpg', 'r')))
```

It gives me error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/pyproject/mysite/tmp/pic.jpg'
```

Please help me someone.

Comment: Are you sure you are using `/tmp/pic.jpg` preceeding slash ?

Comment: Did you try restarting the shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
from django.core.files import File

a.headshot.save('abc.jpg', File(open('/tmp/pic.jpg', 'r')))
```

Comment: post your absolute path of file

Comment: not this, I mean absolute path something like `/var/img.png` or `/user/home/..` . Just enter `pwd` in terminal

Comment: the absolute path is `/Users/streetcoder/pyproject/mysite`

Comment: So put file path `/Users/streetcoder/pyproject/mysite/tmp/pic.jpg`

Comment: it works but still shows different errors and additionally how can I save image path or name in db.

Comment: What is the error. Image name will be what you give as first argument in `save`

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/streetcoder/.virtualenvs/pyenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py", line 91, in save
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    read = property(lambda self: self.file.read)
AttributeError: 'Author' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: Please do what i answered. You are still stick with what you are tried.

Comment: finally I have done ... many many thanks :) just one thing I had to change that is `rb` instead of `r`

Answer (score 0):

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/pyproject/mysite/tmp/pic.jpg'
```

Just see where python is looking for the file.

Please copy the pic.jpg file in same directory where you are running shell command it will work for sure then.

Comment: I run the shell in `pyproject/mysite` and copied the image in `pyproject/mysite` and run the command `a.headshot.save('/abc.jpg', Author(open('/pic.jpg', 'r')))` but still it shows the same error.

Comment: @StreetCoder try remove / from  the beginning for the filename